Не могу добавить DeflateCompressionProvider
Ошибка такого вида:
  Program.cs(74, 23): [CS0311] The type 'Grpc.Net.Compression.DeflateCompressionProvider' cannot be used as type parameter 'TCompressionProvider' in the generic type or method 'CompressionProviderCollection.Add<TCompressionProvider>()'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Grpc.Net.Compression.DeflateCompressionProvider' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.ICompressionProvider'.

Я открыл класс и там условие:
#if NET6_0_OR_GREATER

Однако, если нажать по свойствам проекта в Rider, то в Target framework стоит net6.0.
В чем может быть проблема?
    services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
    {
        options.EnableForHttps = true;
        options.Providers.Add<DeflateCompressionProvider>();
        options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
    });


А код, в котором возникает исключение, есть?

Обновил вопрос кодом

Внимательно посмотрите на пространство имен. Вы используете совершенно другой класс, который не предназначен для того интерфейса, который вы используете. Если зайдете в документацию, то там вовсе не будет DeflateCompressionProvider, а значит это "кастом" (если зайти на метанит, то этот класс там найдете). Так что, будьте внимательней в следующий раз.
